# Laravel 5 mailgun works locally (Mac OS) but nothing happened on live server

Tags: laravel-5, mailgun

I developing a web application using Laravel 5, application needs send email to members when they registered.

I use mailgun as mail driver, everything works fine locally on my Mac Book Pro machine, it means everything should configured correctly, but when I move to Ubuntu server (14.04), the mailgun didn't send any email out neither any error message.

I tried using curl command on server, it works fine, means server should not block any port for mailgun.

Anyone please can help on this issue?

Comment: I'll guess your `.env` is not set properly in production. Check your logs.

Comment: I don't think there should be a .env for production. you have to set the default values in your configuration directory, file: mail.php

Answer (score 0):

As this works from one environment, and not in another, it's very likely to be a configuration problem. This might differ in a few places with mail in Laravel.

- You'll need to check that `pretend` in `config/mail.php` is set to **false**. See [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/mail.php#L122).
- You'll need to make sure your .env file (if you're using .env) is first renamed from `.env.example` to `.env` and then check that the settings are set up correctly for Mailgun. I wrote a small tutorial for Mailgun Laravel 5 [here](http://jamie.sh/tutorials/7/setting-up-mailgun-with-laravel-5) if you have any problems with that.
- You'll need to check that the third party services file in `config/services.php` is configured correctly. More specifically, you need to ensure that the API key is set up correctly.

If none of these work correctly, then you'll almost certainly have some error message in your `storage/logs` folder, I recommend checking here for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this happens due to wrong `env` configuration try this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37154420/5964006). You can simplify the confusion between the `Mail.php` and `.env` settings